AddDbContext Or AddDbContextPool in Multi Tenant Architecture
Which options to use when configuring the DBContext for multi tenant design.
The application is a Dot net core WebAPI, with many customers each having separate Database.
The DBContext connection string is set based on customerId at configure service at the start of every request.
As AddDbContextPool does not create the new context and it gives the available one out of the pool on request. does this mean it will be of same connection string ?
I am currently using AddDbContext and the application insight is warning about memory issue at this point where the connection string is being set

See Pool Fragmentation
